# Testing for non-integers (decimals and strings)

Tags: python, integer, syntax-error

Hi I'm having trouble testing for non-integers in my sript. I'm trying to write a function that returns True if a sudoku is valid and False if not. 2 rule for Sudoku: 1) Each column of the square contains each of the whole numbers from 1 to n exactly once. 2) Each row of the square contains each of the whole numbers from 1 to n exactly once. The problem I'm having is with functions "incorrect4" and "incorrect5". Incorrect4 is showing True even though it's not an integer/whole number and incorrect5 display error message: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. I've tried multiple ways of testing for integers but the value of "1.5" in incorrect4 still shows as True. Additionally I've looked for a solution unsupported operand type error but was unable to fix it. I know there are other, more efficient ways to solve this issue but any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
correct = [[1,2,3],
       [2,3,1],
       [3,1,2]]
incorrect4 = [['a','b','c'],
          ['b','c','a'],
          ['c','a','b']]

incorrect5 = [ [1, 1.5],
           [1.5, 1]]

def check_sudoku(square):
    a = 0
    result = [sum(l) for l in square]
    sum_list = []

    all(type(item)==int for item in square)
    return True

    for col in range(len(square[0])):
        sum_list.append(sum(row[col] for row in square))
        if sum_list == result: return True
    return False 

    for row in range(len(square)):
        if sum(square[a]) == sum(square[a+1]):
            a += 1
            return True
    return False

print check_sudoku(correct)
print check_sudoku(incorrect4)
print check_sudoku(incorrect5)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `isinstance(number,int)` which would return `True` if `number` is an integer?

Comment: Watch out, it might also return true for bools

Comment: That's an odd behavior that I wasn't aware of. Would `isinstance(number,int) and not isinstance(number, bool)` function?

Comment: Also, try to show the stack trace so that we can see the proper error message and their origin.

Comment: It's because bool is a `subclass` of `int` in python.  Shouldn't cause issues though...

Comment: Does this function ever return False? The way it's currently shown, it looks as though it executes 4 lines and then returns True. This function doesn't look as though it can ever get past the first 'return True' line.

Comment: Yeah I assume they b0rked up some indentation or something

Answer (score 1):

Since sudoku puzzles must have integers between 1-9, you don't want some other crazy integers like -4294967296 passing through.  Ergo, I think a check like this would be appropriate:

```
d = 3  # edge-size of your sudoku
all(n in range(1, d**2) for row in sudoku_puzzle for n in row)
```

Where `sudoku_puzzle` can be a list of lists, but you might consider using numpy arrays instead.

You will still need another check to make  sure the dimensions of your `sudoku_puzzle` are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying apply sum() on a type which is other than int.

`all(type(item)==int for item in square)
 return True`

should come before

`result = [sum(l) for l in square]
sum_list = []`

and also for both of the nested for loops, instead of returning a bool value soon after the first loop, you could maintain a flag, set it to true/ false accordingly in each loop, then return the flag

I am also not sure if your indentation is correct after the all clause. the program won't execute beyond that line if am not wrong

Answer (score -2):

if all you are looking for is a function for a float that will return true if the float is an integer, it is built into python. Just when you iterate through, make sure to convert all the numbers to floats, even integers. Not really ideal, but it works great! I use it for my cross validation algorithm in machine learning

```
number = float(some_number)
if number.is_integer():
     #this will execute if the variable is an integer
else:
    #this will execute if the variable is a float
```

Comment: What do you find confusing? The question is to test if something is an integer or not...this function is built into python so it just needs to be used on what you're checking.

Comment: It's built into python?  I think you are living in a fantasy world

Comment: There is a method on floats, but it's not going to work on strings or other `something`s.  Additionally, it's not even going to work properly on whole floats like `1.0`.  And most importantly, it won't work on `int` either!

Comment: well this is odd...I run it in my cross validation algorithm and it works there and I didn't import it from anything or write the code for it...

Comment: actually, you're right, this is to distinguish an integer if it's a float. But the issue asked here is to be False for 1.5, which it is! So it does apply here, I'll edit my response. And right now I am running some code and it works fine on floats like 1.0

Comment: Do what you want, but it still provides a solution to the problem